# I want to display feeds in JSON?

Tags: 7, feeds

I am using aggregator feeds.I have to created feeds.xml file. But i have to create JSON file for Drupal 7? How to create it .Anyone guide to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any existing modules that will do this for aggregator feeds, but there is a way you could do this yourself.  Find the function(s) in the module which create the .xml file and use it to reproduce the functionality for JSON.